# React form submission Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a modal that contains a form. Whenever I submit data through it and console log it, it never works the first time. The second time I submit data through it, the console log of the previous entry. Can anyone identify if I am potentially missing anything?

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOpen(false);
    setSubmission({
      ref: event.target[0].value,
      brand: event.target[1].value,
      iname: event.target[2].value,
      gtin: event.target[3].value,
      qty: 0,
    });
    console.log(submission);
  };
```

Comment: It is because the state is updating asynchronously. You won't get the updated values immediately

Answer (score 3):

Well this is how hooks work, by the time you `console.log(submission)`, the state hasn't changed yet.

This is because when you call setSubmission() it lets react know you want to update the state and puts it in a queue.

If you want to capture the state change, use an `useEffect()` hook

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(submission); // this hook captures the state change and this will have the correct value
}, [submission]);  // think of this as a dependency variable that `useEffect` will listen for changes.
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!